# Teleprompt alert dialog show before showing view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-telephony

I have telprompt alert dialog in my application. I am running in iOS 10.1.1 and iPhone 7 device. Before showing dialog I need to display one view which is hiden in view controller but in iPhone 7 it is not display till I take any action on teleprompt. Below is the code which is working fine on other iOS. Your help would be appreciated.

```
[callView setHidden:NO];
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:msg];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the iPhone 7. It has to do with the version of iOS.

One simple solution is to delay the call to `openURL:` to give your code a chance to complete the hiding of the `callView`.

```
[callView setHidden:NO];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:msg];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
});
```

You should also note that the `UIApplication openURL:` method is deprecated as of iOS 10. It has been replaced with `openURL:options:completionHandler:`. Under iOS 10, using this new method may be another way to solve your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39767062/1226963 for a good explanation of how to use both versions of `openURL:` depending on the current iOS version of the device.

Comment: Thanks my issue is resolve by your given stack overflow link.