# Check for installed apps on iOS 9 and 10

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3

I am trying to check if a user has installed a couple of apps. I need it to work on ios9 and ios 10.
    I am testing on ios9 first and the `schemeAvailable` func is returning true even though the app passed
    is not installed on the device.

```
func schemeAvailable(scheme: String) -> Bool {
   if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
       return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
   }
   return false
}
```

I have added the following to my info.plist i.e. the apps I will check are installed:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>app1</string>
<string>app2</string>
</array>
```

and in my project's info tab, I have added 2 url types and inserted the identifier and url scheme for each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openURL: deprecated in iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548010/openurl-deprecated-in-ios-10)

Comment: @dmorrow i'm explaining an issue with ios9

Comment: `canOpenURL` isn't deprecated

Comment: Can you share the actual url schemes - not `app1` and `app2`?

Comment: @dmorrow com.companyname.app1, com.companyname.app2. They aren't published in the store yet. They are local apps

Comment: @dan apologies, my mistake!!

Comment: Can you debug the `schemeAvailable` method call and confirm what value you are passing for `scheme`?

Comment: @dmorrow should scheme be my app's display name or bundle identifier? followed by :// ? Also my apps are part of an appgroup. Is there any chance this has something to do with my issue?

Comment: @dmorrow  If I run the test passing in "fb://", it reports correctly for installed
        or not but not my own apps. I'm not sure what the protocol is for my app i.e. if it should be displayname or bundle identifier
        and if that needs to be prepended with my app group container's identifier

Comment: @user2363025 - have you set up your app1 and app2 to use a custom URL scheme?

Comment: Be sure to add `CFBundleURLTypes` to app1/info.plist with `app1`.

Comment: @dmorrow When I add this, then schemeAvailable returns true for both even tough 1 is uninstalled

Comment: @Donmag if you mean added the url types to my plist, then yes

Comment: To clarify, which info.plist did you add it to?  We are talking about 3 apps here - app1.app, app2.app and this unnamed app you are checking from.

Comment: @user2363025 - sounds like a little confusion on what needs to be where. I posted an answer with graphics that should help you figure it out.

Comment: @dmorrow in app 3, I had added the CFBundleURLTypes for app1 and app2. I see now via the answer below where I had went wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you do NOT have all registrations correct. Your App1 and App2 each need URL Identifiers and Schemes, and your app that "wants to launch App1 and App2" must have `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` defined.

E.G.

This is in "App1"

[image]

This is in "App2"

[image]

This is in "LauncherApp"

[image]

Then, in "LauncherApp" I can do:

```
    let s = "DMCApp1://TestMe"
    let customURL: URL = URL(string: s)!

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(customURL) {
        print("YES - I can open App1 !!!")
        UIApplication.shared.open(customURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        print("NO - App1 is not available.")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the other apps' schemes on your app plist. If you do that you app becomes the responder to URL with that scheme and always be true.

canOpenURL method is not marked as deprecated on [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl)

I copy a snippet with part of the code I use to open app url by custom schemes...

```
/**
    Abre los perfiles de la app en las distintas redes sociales.

    - Parameters:
        - url: Esquema personalizado de la app
        - secondaryURL: Si la app no está presente en el dispositivo abrimos su version web (twitter, facebook, etc...)
*/    
    func open(_ url: String, secondaryURL: String? = nil) -> Void
        {
            if let url = URL(string: url), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
            }
            else if let secondaryURL = secondaryURL, let url = URL(string: secondaryURL), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
            }
            else 
            {
                print("No se puede hacer nada de nada.\r\napp_url: \(url)")
            }
        }
```

And here's an example. I try to open twitter app, and if not presented, open Safari and shows the twitter web page.

```
@IBAction private func handleTwitterButtonTap(sender: UIButton) -> Void
{
    let twitter_app_url: String = "twitter://user?screen_name=GetPomodoroApp"
    let twitter_web_url: String = "https://twitter.com/GetPomodoroApp"

    self.open(twitter_app_url, secondaryURL: twitter_web_url)
}
```

Comment: if I remove the 2 url types, identifier and url scheme in my project's info tab,
    then I get
    failed for URL: "app1://" - error: "(null)" AND
    failed for URL: "app2://" - error: "(null)"
    even though app2 is installed

Comment: Hi @user2363025. I've add an example.

Comment: This answer is confusing. The schemes must be listed under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`.

Comment: Schemes must be listed for your own app (your own scheme). But no register external schemes, like twitter, facebook... @rmaddy

Comment: @Adolfo That's incorrect. Any URL scheme you use with `canOpenURL` must be listed under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. This has been a requirement since iOS 9.

Comment: Try with instagram (for example). let instagram_app_url: String = "instagram://user?username="..." ;) @rmaddy

Comment: Hi @rmaddy You're right, with canOpenURL you need to register the scheme. I *change* the conversation in my mind to `openURL` ;)