# is it possible to get info about another apps on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm doing an  iOS app and I want to get some data about my users.
Is it possible to get information about another apps on user's phone? At list name of all apps on iphone, or last launching time?

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: [Check for installed apps on iOS 9 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651882/check-for-installed-apps-on-ios-9-and-10)

HackingwithSwift.com also has a good article on this: [How to check whether your other apps are installed](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-check-whether-your-other-apps-are-installed)

The HWS video on this warns that "you may have to provide an explanation to the review team if you query too many apps or apps that aren't yours"