# Custom URL Scheme Obj-C iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make a internet radio app, that can open whatsapp. I know that you cant directly open whatsapp and direct the message to a specific contact, so I am now redirecting the whatsapp button to a link and it will open in safari. Now, I tried following tutorials, but it always says that the 'open url is deprecated'. Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)btnWa:(id)sender {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62------&text=&source=&data="]];
```

Comment: It doesn't just say it's deprecated: it also tells you that you should use openURL:options:completionHandler:

Answer (score 2):

Use Open Url with Completion Handler see this for more information:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548010/openurl-deprecated-in-ios-10)