# The “prefs” URL Scheme not working in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode8

I can't get the "prefs" URL Scheme to work in iOS 10.
It's set up correctly since the same App works fine on iOS 9.

Is this a bug or did it get renamed / removed?

Code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"];
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url]; 
}
```

Comment: What has the version of Xcode got to do with it?

Comment: @Droppy I can't get the "prefs" URL Scheme to work in iOS 10.
 correctly since the same App works fine on iOS 9.

Comment: You should update your question with those details.

Comment: Please see the link: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/

Comment: @Droppy You know the answer

Comment: See this 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964264/openurl-in-ios10    , 2. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html , 3. http://pastebin.com/SrhqHjth

Comment: @SaurabhJain this code also not working for iOS 10  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

Answer (score 3):

In order directly open location settings. Use the below code:

```
// This will open ios devices location settings in iOS 10
  if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"openURL:options:completionHandler:")]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
  }
  else {
// This will open ios devices location settings in below iOS 10
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]]) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
    }
  }
```

Comment: "App-Prefs:root" or "prefs:root" are considered as private API's. Avoid using them otherwise the app may get rejected during review.

Answer (score 3):

Got to replace `prefs` with `App-Prefs`, here is my Swift helper methods to support both iOS 10 and lower, tested on iOS 9 & 10

```
class Helper {

    static func openLocationSettings() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            openSettings(url: "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION")
        } else {
            openSettings(url: "prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES")
        }
    }

    static func openSettings(url: String) {
        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: url), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) else { return }

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl)
        }
    }

}
```

Example 1 **Open Location Settings:**

```
Helper.openLocationSettings()
```

Example 2 **Open Application Settings:**

```
Helper.openSettings(url: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
```

Answer (score 2):

The new method in iOS 10:

```
//Objective-C
- (void)openURL:(NSURL*)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options
  completionHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL success))completion


// Swift
open func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:],
  completionHandler completion: (@escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```

Opening a URL with iOS 10

```
// Objective-C
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

// Swift
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

For more info, refer to [this link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/)

Comment: This code also not working for iOS 10  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to verify method availability first and then use appropriate method.

```
   if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) 
   {
      [application openURL:URL options:@{}
         completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

            NSLog(@"Open URL Scheme %@: %d",scheme,success);
      }];
   } 
   else 
   {
      BOOL success = [application openURL:URL];
      NSLog(@"Open URL Scheme %@: %d",scheme,success);
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add your scheme to your plist as one of your URLSchemes

Answer (score 0):

`prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES` is working for below iOS 10...so checked for `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` and `App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION`. Both are working for me.... Got hint by @Rajan Balan.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]]) {
     if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"10")) {
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"]];

          // Below code is also working in iOS 10 to open location services
          // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];

     } else {
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
     }
}
```

Where

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```