# OpenUrl not working on iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios10

My app uses openURL to open Google Maps app.
It works on iOS 9 but not on iOS 10.

I understand that this method was deprecated on iOS 10, and there's a new one with more parameters.
However, I saw everywhere that it should still work, and changing to the new method will only prevent a warning in the xCode.
I also want to still support iOS 9 and lower.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: You can find a deatiled description on alternatives here http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/ .

Comment: I read that, in the comments the author says: "The method is not dropped in iOS 10 but you will get a warning in Xcode when you build against the iOS 10 SDK". As I said - It should work, only a warning would be prevented.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Not really :) It's of the company I work at. I noticed that it only happens with opening an app, if i put an http url it works.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Have you added the appropriate value to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html

Comment: Please try this link which will gives you more detail:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/

Comment: @Paulw11 That's what I missed! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenURL in iOS10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964264/openurl-in-ios10)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in **info.plist** file.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
     <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    </array>
```

Use this....

**Objective c**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://maps.google.com/maps"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

**Swift 4**

```
 guard let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://maps.google.com/maps") else {
      return //be safe
 }

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
   UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```