# How to make a URL Run when a notification action is pressed?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

I created a notification with two actions. One of my actions is called "Cancel", while the other is called "Call". How do I make the "Call" action run a URL that is in a comment that I added to my code. Here is my code:

```
  func notificationFires(){

    /**
     URL Code:

     if let url = URL(string: "tel://") {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
     }


**/

    let call = UNNotificationAction(identifier:"call", title:"Call", options:[.foreground])
    let cancel = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "cancel", title: "Cancel", options: [.destructive ])
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "category", actions: [call, cancel], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.category = "category"
    // 2

    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.fireDate = datePicker.date

    // 3
    if textField.text == "" {

        notification.alertBody = "You have a call right now!"

    }
    else{

        notification.alertBody = self.textField.text

    }
    // 4
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
    // 5
    // 6
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    // 7

    func application(application: UIApplication!, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier:String!, forLocalNotification notification:UILocalNotification!, completionHandler: (() -> Void)!){

        if (identifier == "call"){
            if let url = URL(string: "tel://2162964785") {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
            }
        }else if (identifier == "cancel"){

        }

    }

    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)



    func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveLocalNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Recieved: notification")



        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ["notification"])




    }

}
```

Comment: perhaps the following would be helpful
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964264/openurl-in-ios10?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your notification is working correctly, you can conform to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to handle the "call" action.

Something like:

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if response.actionIdentifier == "call" {
            let body = response.notification.request.content.body

            if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(body)") {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

The `body` constant would be set to the phone number that you want to "open".

Also, its important to note that this has to be tested on an actual device. Opening a `tel` scheme does nothing in the simulator.

**UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate API Reference:** https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate

**EDIT:**

*You* do not call the delegate method. Instead you implement it. The delegate method is called by the `UNUserNotificationCenter`.

To get this working, its important to ensure that you set the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current()` delegate property to a class that will conform to the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol.

For example, if you are handling your notification in your `AppDelegate`, you may have something like the following method:

```
func callNotification() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.center()

    // TODO: - Create your actions, category, content, trigger and request...

    center.delegate = self // Important!

    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

The method above would be responsible for defining your notification and scheduling it. For brevity, I have left out all of the code that would define the notification since you indicated that this is working. Instead you should note that the `delegate` property is being set to `self`.

Then in an extension, you would make the `AppDelegate` conform to the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and implement the required methods.

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if response.actionIdentifier == "call" {
            let body = response.notification.request.content.body

            if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(body)") {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now because your `AppDelegate` conforms to the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol and you set `self` (`AppDelegate`) as the `UNUserNotificationCenter`'s delegate, **your implementation** of the `userNotification(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` method will be called.

Comment: @Krish Did you get an error? Did you test on the simulator or an actual device? Is the notification appearing?

Comment: No I did not get an error, and I did test it on my actual phone. The notification does pop up, although when I tap on the "Call" button, all it does is bring me into the app instead of running the URL to call someone.

Comment: @Krish It should bring you to your app and the `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` method should handle the opening of the `tel` scheme. Is the delegate method getting called?

Comment: Where would I need to call the delegate method?

Comment: And how do I call the delegate method?

Comment: @krish I have updated my answer with details on how to implement the delegate.

Comment: NOTE: I setup my whole notification in ViewController.swift

Comment: Is it okay if I put this in my notificationFires() function in my ViewController

Comment: @krish That would be fine. However, you should ensure that your delegate object is set early on in your app's lifecycle, preferably in your `AppDelegate`'s `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` or `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` methods. See Apple's important note [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate).