# Invalid App Store link when opening in Safari on iOS Simulator using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, ios-simulator, openurl

I am currently working on a Swift project, and I have a button that, when pressed, should open a specific link. I've encountered an issue where using an **App Store app link** (let's say : `https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tiny-wings/id417817520` ) results in an "invalid" response, while other links open correctly in the Safari browser of the iOS Simulator.

My code :

```
let appStoreLink =  "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tiny-wings/id417817520"
       
if let url = URL(string: appStoreLink), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
   print("Invalid URL or unable to open the link.")
}
```

Snapshot of Simulator Output:
[image]

Is there a specific approach or alternative method I should use when dealing with App Store links in this context?

Comment: Where did you get invalid response? `UIApplication.shared.open` doesn't provide any response feedbacks. Also you don't need canOpenURL check for HTTP links

Comment: "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" - this popup message is showing in my simulator safari browser when i press the link. But if i copy the same address and paste in my mac saferi browser, its correctly redirecting the App store apps .

Comment: What is the mac-app-store tag for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenURL in iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964264/openurl-in-ios10)

Comment: Consider using [`SKStoreProductViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller) to allow the user to view the app without leaving your app

Comment: @ElTomato , No. That was not the answer of my question.  "mac-app-store" tag used because it was stack overflow AI suggested. Btw i removed it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can not open the `apps.apple` domain from the simulator. Maybe Apple has a mechanism to block navigation to this domain, and prevent you from installing apps on the simulator. You can also try to search for the App Store via Safari directly, even if the result shows up, you can't do anything about it. The same error appears when you tap on this search result:

[image]

However, I am pretty sure it will work in the production environment. It's guaranteed and also is a basic case.

Comment: Confirming, that it works fine on a real device